# Horizontal SUVAT problem (AS Level)

Tags: calculus, problem-solving, word-problem, kinematics, projectile-motion

Could someone please explain how you get the answer for the following question:

```
A car of mass 1300 kg is traveling at a speed of 30ms^-1 along a straight horizontal
motorway when the driver sees a traffic jam ahead and applies the brakes for 15 s.
The car covers a distance of 270 m while the driver is braking. 

a) Find the speed of the car at the end of the 15 s braking interval.
```

My Working:

```
S = 1/2(v-u)t
270=15V-1/2(2)(15)^2
15V=495
V=33
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you include some of your work? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it. Please check now.

Comment: You want to use the fact that the work done is the change in kinetic energy and that the force applied by the brakes is constant on the fifteen second time interval during which the brakes were applied. So you get $$\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2=Fd$$ $$\frac{v_f-v_0}{15}=\frac{F}{m}$$ Now you can solve this system for $v_f$ which I'm getting to equal $6$

Comment: I see, makes sense now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the problem statement let $v_0= 30 \frac{m}{s}$, $m=1300 kg$, $\Delta x=270m$, $\Delta t=15s$, and let the force applied to the breaks be $F_b$.  We have,
$$
ma=-F_b
$$
which can be written,
$$
mv\frac{dv}{dx}=-F_b
$$
Integrating we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}v^2 |_{v_0}^{v_f}=-F_b \Delta x\\
\frac{1}{2}v_f^2=-F_b \Delta x + \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2\\
v_f = \sqrt{\frac{2}{m}(-F_b \Delta x + \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2)}
$$
We need to determine $F_b$.  Write,
$$
m\frac{dv}{dt}=-F_b
$$
integrate to get
$$
v=\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{-F_b}{m}t + v_0
$$
Integrate again to get
$$
\Delta x=\frac{-F_b}{2m} t^2 + v_0 t\\
F_b=2m\frac{( v_0 t-\Delta x)}{t^2}
$$
Substituting $F_b$ in the equation for final velocity, we find,
$$
v_f = \sqrt{ v_0^2 - \frac{4\Delta x (  v_0 t -\Delta x)}{t^2}}
$$